# Dart: best type to store currency

Tags: dart, currency

In Java currency is usually stored in `BigDecimal`. But what to use to store currency values in Dart? `BigInt` doesn't seem to be a solution because it is for integer values only.

Comment: You can try the [money](https://pub.dev/packages/money) package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely do *not* use `double`s for an accounting application.  Binary floating point numbers inherently cannot represent exact decimal values, which can lead to [inaccurate calculations for seemingly trivial operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/).  Even though the errors will be small, they can eventually accumulate into larger errors.  Setting decimal precision on binary numbers doesn't really make sense.

For currency, you instead either should something intended to store decimal values (e.g. [`package:decimal`](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal)) or should use [fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) to store cents (or whatever the smallest amount of currency is that you want to track).  For example, instead of using `double`s to store values such as $1.23, use `int`s to store amounts in the smallest unit of currency (e.g. 123 cents).  Then you can use helper classes to format the amounts wherever they're displayed.  For example:

```dart
class Money {
   int cents;

   Money({required this.cents});

   @override
   String toString() => (cents / 100).toStringAsFixed(2);

   Money operator +(Money other) => Money(cents: cents + other.cents);

   // Add other operations as desired.
}
```