# Flutter substracted double value has many decimal points

Tags: flutter, dart

when i run this code

```
_selectedCartList.forEach((group) {
    group.cartModel.where((cartModel) => !cartModel.isSelected).forEach((cart) {
      print('taxx $_tax - ${cart.tax} * ${cart.quantity}');
      _tax -= cart.tax * cart.quantity;
    });
  });
```

this is what I got in the log

```
I/flutter ( 2664): taxx 243863.4 - 7562.5 * 1
I/flutter ( 2664): taxx 236300.9 - 119669.0 * 1
I/flutter ( 2664): taxx 116631.9 - 114829.0 * 1
I/flutter ( 2664): taxx 1802.8999999999942 - 1802.9 * 1
```

the taxx 243863.4 is the initial value.
and in this part when things go wrong:

```
I/flutter ( 2664): taxx 116631.9 - 114829.0 * 1
I/flutter ( 2664): taxx 1802.8999999999942 - 1802.9 * 1
```

when I subtract 116631.9 - 114829.0 it gives me 1802.8999999999942 which something that's not supposed to

**ANSWER FOR FLUTTER**

as [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dud) said in the comment the explanation for this behavior is this [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

as for the solution in the flutter itself, i use this

```
_selectedCartList.forEach((group) {
    String _roundedTax;
    group.cartModel.where((cartModel) => !cartModel.isSelected).forEach((cart) {
      _roundedTax = _tax.toStringAsFixed(1);
      _tax = double.parse(_roundedTax);
      print('taxx $_tax - ${cart.tax} * ${cart.quantity}');         
      _tax -= cart.tax * cart.quantity;
    });
  });
```

and the result is exactly how i want

```
I/flutter ( 2664): taxx 243863.4 - 7562.5 * 1
I/flutter ( 2664): taxx 236300.9 - 119669.0 * 1
I/flutter ( 2664): taxx 116631.9 - 114829.0 * 1
I/flutter ( 2664): taxx 1802.9 - 1802.9 * 1
```

Comment: should i round the result of subtracted value? if yes I wonder what caused this problem

Comment: [Do *not* use `double` for storing currency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57446115/).  Your "solution" does not solve the fundamental problem and can eventually accumulate error.